# Windows Driver for Arduino error code 22

Tags: communication, windows, arduino-mini

I'm trying to use avrdude to load an Arduino program with the console, but I have a Windows 7 x86 Professional with Service Pack 1 (old PC).  When I install the Arduino driver that comes with the IDE manually, with pnputil.exe, in the Windows 7 on PCs that have these processors:

- Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz
- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E6400 @ 2.13GHz
- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz

I see that the drivers don't work properly.  I get error code 22 in some cases.  And in other cases, the Windows system disables the Arduino in the Windows devices and prevents enabling the COM device.

But, if I install the Arduino IDE or manually install the Windows driver on Core i3, Core i5 and i7 in Windows 7, 8 , 10, the response is perfect.  But, in the others I get error code -22 or Windows doesn't allow to enabling the device.

Has anyone had the same problem and how did you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the drivers as administrator? Does the user with that you installed them have full admin privileges?

Comment: Yes i install the driver as administrator